# Why not the most dancing person?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, superlatives, structure

I would like to know why we can say you are the most boring person I have ever met but it is incorrect to write you are the most dancing person I have ever met.

Comment: But for example in the song "dancing queen" . Dancing is an adjective for a queen but not for a person is it ?

Comment: Yes I was thinking of that when I wrote the comment. Abba are/were Swedish, and not native speakers. Some gerund verbs can become noun-adjectives, e.g. a fencing master (a fencing teacher or coach) but we do not say someone is a very fencing person.

Comment: Gerunds and adjectives can be difficult to distinguish. I had to think for a bit to come up with an example of dancing that was definitely an adjective (dancing shoes) before I could answer confidently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“dancing” is an *absolute*, or *non-comparative*, adjective. That means it has no meaningful degree; you can’t be more (or less) dancing than someone else.

“boring” is a *comparative*, or *non-absolute*,  adjective. One person can be more or less boring than another.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a grammar name . You are very helpful